# Split Testing like Netlify using Cloudfront and Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, netlify

### Current Stack

I am using a **cloudfront** to distribute my static website objects that live in an **S3 bucket**. I am using **Route53** to handle my DNS routing and health checking.

### What I'd like to accomplish

I recently came across Netlify that does [Split testing](https://www.netlify.com/docs/split-testing/) between different feature Branches. I would like to stick with my current stack on AWS but would like to build in this functionality for AB testing.

### What I tried

Originally, I wanted to have a Route53 serve 2 separate Cloudfront services each with their own S3 bucket. I would use Weighted Round Robin to distribute 10% of traffic to the testing environment and the other 90% to the production environment. I [learned quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557480/weighted-round-robin-dns-between-2-cloudfront-distributions) that Amazon does not allow the same domain to serve 2 different Cloudfront services each serving their own S3.

The [other option](http://[]%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-a-b-testing) was to do this testing at the edge node of my cloudfront service. This would require me to serve two different objects to from the same S3, which seems very messy and not scalable.

### My question

Is it even possible to replicate what Netlify does with Split testing when using AWS? If so, how can I implement it? If not, what is my next best option for AB testing a static website?